# Apache Axis2 Java client to access Bronto SOAP WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, bronto

I've downloaded Apache Axis2, using the following link:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis2/1_4_1/axis2-1.4.1-bin.zip

Then I used the following command to generate java classes:
wsdl2java.sh -uri https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl
total generated src:
BrontoSoapApiImplServiceStub.java
BrontoSoapApiImplServiceCallbackHandler.java
ApiExceptionException0.java

I was able to login using the following.

```
BrontoSoapApiImplServiceStub stub;

// Get the stub...

LoginE loginE = new LoginE();
Login login = new Login();

login.setApiToken("your token here");
loginE.setLogin(login);

// Call the web service; login
stub.login(loginE);
```

Now I try to addContacts, and needs SessionHeaderE, but I can't seem to link login to the sessionId, the following code is not right. I'm imaging after login, I should be able to get some session info. But I can't seem to find.

```
SessionHeader sessionHeader = new SessionHeader();
sessionHeader.setSessionId(param)  // I don't know how to get sessionId from login info
SessionHeaderE sessionHeaderE = new SessionHeaderE();
sessionHeaderE.setSessionHeader(sessionHeader);
.....
AddContactsResponseE responseE = stub.addContacts(addContactsE, sessionHeaderE);
```

By the way, this is my first time working with Axis. Not sure what's the best way to approach the problem.
BrontoSoapApiImplServiceStub.java has more than 200,000 lines in it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from http://www.experts-exchange.com

String sessionId = stub.login(loginE).getLoginResponse().get_return();

Thanks.

Comment: Where at Experts Exchange did you get the answer?